# Power BI Paginated Report with matrix visual, with values on rows, and one record per page

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

The below visual was taken from an existing Power BI report. The way it is setup is as follows:

1. Matrix visual
2. Attributes in values (no row or column attributes)
3. Values on rows
4. Value aggregation is using first record
5. Page filters on a single table record (all values in visual sourced from this table)

Is there a way to achieve the same visual in a Power BI paginated report?

I have not figured out a way to create a paginated report that allows the user to show values on the rows and toggle to the next page to get the next record.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of data I'll just have to offer a general approach.

Let's say you have an employee table and you dataset query returnd

| EmpID | FirstName | LastName | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Smith | 30000 |
| 2 | Mary | Scary | 40000 |
| 3 | Frank | Lee | 50000 |

Add a table you your report. It will default to a single row in the "details" row group. Add 2 more rows inside the "details" row group by right-clicking then "Insert Row / Inside Group - Below".

Once you have three rows delete all columns except 1, in the first row select the First name, in the second rows, the last name and in the third row select the salary.

Now, either from the rowgroup panel under the main designer, or from a cell in the tablix, right-click then choose "Add Group / Parent Group"

In the dialogue, choose "EmpID" as the group column and optionally add a header (in your case you probably want this). You may find you get an additional column added, you can remove this (but NOT the group).

Now in the row groups panel under the main design window, right click your new parent gorup, choose properties, then on the "Page Breaks" tab, select "between instances".

That should do what you want

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you for the quick reply!